# Getting error when running npx webpack --config webpack.config.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Have been trying to run `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js` since many packages including web3 are not compatible with Webpack v5 without adding fallbacks for the polyfils.

This is the error I am recieving

> [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - configuration.module.rules[1] should be one of these:
>   ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
>   -> A rule.
>   Details:
>   * configuration.module.rules[1].loader should be a non-empty string.
>   -> A loader request.

Here is my webpack.config.json:

```
    const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
      ],
      module:{
        rules:[{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$|jsx/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            assert: require.resolve('assert'),
            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
            https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
            os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
        },
    },
};
```

Would really appreciate any insight on why this error is popping up, thank you in advance!

Comment: May be something to do with the eslint-loader?

Comment: is this something i can do? test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{ 
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] },
                  }, { 
                    loader: ESLintPlugin.loader
                  }]